# What is the correct definition for "Shia"?

Tags: shiism, islamic-basis, definitions

السلام عليكم

Is Google given definition correct?

> one of the two main branches of Islam, followed especially in Iran,
>   that rejects the first three Sunni caliphs and regards Ali, the fourth
>   caliph, as Muhammad's first true successor.

And if is not, please, share with me the most precise one.

**P.S.** Surely, "Deeds are by intentions." Mine - is to know more and be objective.
Peace be upon all seekers of Truth beyond the arrogance.

Comment: Did you look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam

Comment: Dear jvjurad, I strongly suggest you to peruse the following sites as related issues to your significant querstion:   1:  http://www.al-islam.org/shiite-encyclopedia-ahlul-bayt-dilp-team/who-are-ahlul-bayt-part-1
     ________________________________      2: http://www.al-islam.org/message-thaqalayn/vol2-n2-3/ahl-al-bayt-its-meaning-and-origin/ahlul-bayt-its-meaning-and-origin
   _________________________________     3: http://www.al-islam.org/shiite-encyclopedia-ahlul-bayt-dilp-team

Answer (score 1):

```
                                  In the name of Allah
```

**Literally,** it has two meanings, among: following an individual or a group.

**Idiomatically,** it is said/applied for the Muslims who believe (accept) the immediate Imamate/Caliphate of Ali (Imam Ali (a.s.)) and likewise believe that:

Imams and the successor of Prophet Muhammad are determined (appointed) through Nass-al-Shar'i. And the Imamate of Imam Ali (a.s.) and other Shi'a Imams has proved by Nass-al-Shar’i too.

**Note:** Nass is deemed as a Fiqhi expression which is said to the Hokm (ruling) which is inferred from the Holy Quran apparent or Prophet and Imam’s hadiths.

---

**According to Wikipedia:**

> **Shia** (/ˈʃiːə/; Arabic: شيعة‎‎ Shīʿah, from Shīʻatu ʻAlī, followers of Ali, Persian: شیعه‎‎ Shīye or Shīʿee) is a branch of Islam which
>   holds that the Islamic prophet Muhammad designated Ali ibn Abi Talib
>   as his successor (Caliph). Shia Islam primarily contrasts with Sunni
>   Islam, whose adherents believe that Muhammad did not appoint a
>   successor. Instead they consider Abu Bakr (who was appointed Caliph
>   through a Shura, i.e. consensus) to be the correct Caliph.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam

---

Source:

[www.wikifeqh.ir](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%B9%D9%87)